# Unable to upload a file using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to the reactjs, my objective is to upload a file in the form (form which contacts no.of data i.e., name, email, phone number, etc..), I couldn't able to figure it out how to upload the file. i mean in which format do i need to upload the file. In Backend, we're using iform file similar to this link "[File upload with ASP.Net Core 2.0 Web API and React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391735/file-upload-with-asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-and-react-js)" and swagger looks in this way:

[image: snap]

Here is the code:

```
 <Form.Field>
                <label>File upload </label>
                <Button as="label" htmlFor="file" type="button" animated="fade">
                  <Button.Content visible>
                    <Icon name="file" />
                  </Button.Content>
                  <Button.Content hidden>Choose a File</Button.Content>
                </Button>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  hidden
                  onChange={this.props.FileCheck}
                />
                <Form.Input
                  fluid
                  label="File Chosen: "
                  placeholder="Use the above bar to browse your file system"
                  readOnly
                  value={this.state.fileName}
                />
</Form.Field>
```

Here is the sample one i just created for upload file only "https://codesandbox.io/s/red-feather-77v26".

i'm getting in this way: 
[image: console output]

When i click on submit it is showing unsupported media file. can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Can you try removing ```headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }``` just don't assign anything because normally axios itself would recognize it.. And also for file upload the content type is ```multipart/form-data``` ..

Comment: Also you should send the ```formData``` as data to the request..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan - How to send formData as request? moreover i have multiple input fields in Display.js like my mentioned in my query (eg: name, email, phonenumber, zipcode.....etc.,) Could you please help me in that?

Comment: You need to append everything (all input values) into formData which you already created .. Pass the appended data into request..   Please look into this link for better understanding  https://codesandbox.io/s/kkpq42r413 .. As you are using local api call it is harder to give exact solution and hence I am using comment section.. In general, you need to pass the formData for uploading file to backend in that api call you also can append other input values.. Also as like I said in first comment you should remove/change the ```Content-Type``` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewrite FileUpload Component and Display Component as below. Please check it. It should work.

**FileUpload Component**

```
import React from "react";
import {Grid, Label, Button, Icon, Form} from "semantic-ui-react";

export default class FIleUpload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    fileUpload = (e) => {
        this.props.setFile(e.target.files[0], e.target.files[0].name);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Row>
                    <Label className="FileLab">File Upload</Label>
                    <Button as="label" htmlFor="file" type="button" animated="fade">
                        <Button.Content visible>Choose a File</Button.Content>
                        <Button.Content hidden>
                            <Icon name="file"/>
                        </Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <input type="file" id="file" hidden onChange={this.fileUpload}/>

                    <Form.Input
                        className="myfileName"
                        label="file name"
                        placeholder="Use the above bar to browse your file system"
                        readOnly
                        value={this.props.fileName}
                    />
                </Grid.Row>
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```

**Display Component**

```
import React from "react";
import {render} from "react-dom";
import {Form, Button} from "semantic-ui-react";
import axios from "axios";
import FIleUpload from "./FIleUpload";

export default class Display extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: null,
            fileName: ""
        };
    }

    setFile = (file, name) => {
        this.setState({
            file: file,
            fileName: name
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.state.file);
        const data = {
            file: this.state.file,
            fileName: this.state.fileName
        };
        axios
            .post(`/api/FormDetails`, data, {
                headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
            })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form>
                    <FIleUpload setFile={this.setFile}/>
                    <br/>
                    <Form.Group align="center">
                        <Form.Field fluid control={Button} onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                            {" "}
                            SUBMIT{" "}
                        </Form.Field>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Still i'm getting unsupported media file (415 error)

Comment: My bad, I have some typo in Display Component in the line headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}. Can you please try again

Comment: Still i'm getting the same error and i've updated in my query to show what is appearing in console while submitting the data

Comment: When I run your code, I was getting error and that's why I updated your code and put it here as answer but your code in not updated in sandbox according to my answer. can you please update that. Moreover, what is the error that you are getting

Comment: i've updated my code in sandbox and i'm getting error as ***POST http://localhost:3000/api/FormDetails 415 (unsupported media type)***

Comment: Hi, in display Component, you did not change this code headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } But I already advise you to write the code headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}

Comment: hi, Why you unaccept the answer? is there any issue?